# Core for an unbounded operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

A symmetric operator $T$ is called essentially self-adjoint if its 
closure $T$ is self-adjoint. If $T$ is closed, a subset $D \subset D(T)$ is called a **core** for $T$ 
if $\overline {T\upharpoonleft D} = T$. So any dense subset of $D(T)$ is a core for $T$.

I would like to know about if there are any other equivalent conditions for a subset $D \subset D(T)$ to be a core for $T$.

Answer (score 12):

No, it's not true that any dense subset of $D(T)$ is a core for $T$.  For $D \subseteq D(T)$ to be a core for $T$, what you want is $\{(x,Tx): x \in D\}$ to be dense in the graph $\{(x,Tx): x \in D(T)\}$ of $T$ (as subsets of ${\mathscr H} \times {\mathscr H}$, with the norm topology).

Equivalently, for any $x \in D(T)$ there exists a sequence $x_n \in D$ such
that $\|x_n  - x\| + \|T x_n - Tx\| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: yeah that's true. I was assuming graph norm.

Comment: I linked to your answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2783500/understanding-the-core-of-an-operator-or-map (and would appreciate any feedback)

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, there is a nice check:**

A subset $\mathcal{D}\subseteq\mathcal{D}(A)$ is a core for a closed operator $A$ iff the following condition is satisfied:
$$(x_0,Ax_0)\perp(x,A\restriction_\mathcal{D}x)\text{ for all }x\in\mathcal{D}\implies x_0=0$$

That condition basically comes from the orthogonal decomposition for closed subspaces:
$$\mathcal{G}(A)=\overline{\mathcal{G}(A\restriction_\mathcal{D})}\oplus\mathcal{G}(A\restriction_\mathcal{D})^\perp$$
But one has to be aware that the operator must have been closed so that:
$$A\text{ closed}\implies\mathcal{G}(A)\text{ closed}\implies\mathcal{G}(A)\text{ complete}$$

**And yes, there is the ready core:**

For a closed and densely defined operator a core is given by: $\mathcal{D}(A^*A)$

That one basically comes while using the above from a subtle investigation of: $(1+A^*A)$

Comment: Do you know a reference for the domain of $A^\ast A$ being a core of $A$?

Comment: @shuhalo: Yes, have a look at Weidmann, Lineare Operatoren, Satz 4.11 a.